# Sheaf inclusion for globally generated coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, birational-geometry

This is an Exercise in Popa's note: Kodaira dimension of algebraic varieties, page 32.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a globally generated coherent sheaf of generic rank $r$ on a variety $X$. Then there exists a sheaf inclusion:
$$\mathcal O_X^{\oplus r}\hookrightarrow \mathcal F.$$

I know a baby version stating that if a line bundle $L$ admits a nonzero global section, then we have a sheaf inclusion $\mathcal O_X\hookrightarrow L$ defined by $1_x\mapsto s_x.$

But for our case, I cannot see how to find the suitable map to verify the injectivity. Since the generic rank is $r$, we could at least find $r$ global nonzero sections, then how to explain the injectivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a space of global sections of $F$ generating $F$. If $v \in V$ is a general element, the corresponding morphism $v \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to F$ is injective. Let
$$
F' := \mathrm{Coker}(v \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to F),
\qquad 
V' := V / \langle v \rangle.
$$
Then $F'$ is a coherent sheaf of generic rank $r - 1$ and $V'$ is a space of global sections of $F'$ generating it. Now the required result follows by induction.

EDIT. Indeed, by induction there is a subspace $U' \subset V'$ of dimension $r - 1$ such that the map $U' \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to F'$ is injective. Let $U \subset V$ be the preimage of $U'$ in $V$, this is a subspace of dimension $r$. Then it is straightforward to check that $U \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to F$ is injective.

Comment: Dear @Sasha, thanks! But I still have one question looking forward to your response,

so now we have an exact sequence 

$$0\rightarrow\mathcal O_X\rightarrow F\rightarrow {F^\prime}\rightarrow 0,$$
and an inclusion $\mathcal O_X^{\oplus {r-1}}\hookrightarrow F^\prime$, then how can we infer the claim as the exact sequence may not splits?

Comment: @Steve: The sequence need not to split, but the sections lift, because they are contained in $V'$; see the addition to my answer above.